# JVM-Crash in JNI call ReleaseStringUTFChars, only on Windows 7, Windows XP fine

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface, jvm-crash

Here is an excerpt of C++ code that is called from a Java JVM via JNI:

```
(JNIEnv *pJniEnv, jobject, jstring pDllName)
    {
           string dllName(pJniEnv->GetStringUTFChars(pDllName, NULL));

           // stuff happens here like
           HINSTANCE loadedDll = LoadLibrary(dllName.c_str());

           pJniEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pDllName, dllName.c_str());

           return ...;
    }
```

This works in Windows XP but crashes in Windows 7 with an access violation exception, in the line

```
 pJniEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pDllName, dllName.c_str());
```

The error message is:

> First-chance exception at 0x77355F29 (ntdll.dll) in java.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x002B0D52.

I'd be thankful for any clues.

JRE version: 6.0_27-b07, Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode windows-x86 ), C++ Code was built with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for `GetStringUTFChars()` states:

> Returns a pointer to an array of UTF-8 characters of the string.
>   This array is valid until it is released by ReleaseStringUTFChars.

The documentation for `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` states (where `string` is the first argument and `utf` is the second argument):

> Informs the virtual machine implementation that native code no
>   longer needs access to the native string utf. The utf argument
>   is a pointer derived from string using GetStringUTFChars.

In the posted code, `dllName.c_str()` is being passed as the second argument to `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` which is incorrect as `c_str()` is owned by `dllName` (`std::string`'s constructor makes a *copy* of its argument) and is not dervied from `pDllName`. The fact this works on one platform and not another suggests undefined behaviour.

To correct:

```
const jbyte* pDllName_string = pJniEnv->GetStringUTFChars(pDllName, NULL);
std::string dllName(pDllName_string);
pJniEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pDllName, pDllName_string);

/* Use 'dllName' */
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I will accept your answer and report back later if it has worked (it may take a while to try it out).

Comment: It would seem that GetStringUTFChars does not return a jbyte* but rather a char*...

Comment: @TimvanBeek That is a distinction without a difference. They're the same thing.

Comment: @hmjd: Thanks again, your solution was tested successfully .